# Write query using JOINS

Tags: sql, join

```
select 
    store, sum(value) 
from 
    rms.sa_tran_head 
where
    store_day_seq_no in (select store_day_seq_no 
                         from rms.sa_store_day 
                         where store in (3003)
                           and business_date = '01-JAN-2015') 
    and tran_type in ('SALE', 'RETURN') 
group by 
    store;
```

How to write the above query using JOINS..

```
SELECT 
    sd.store, 
    SUM(TH.VALUE) AS GROSS , 
    SUM(ti.qty) AS QTY
FROM rms.sa_tran_head AS th
    JOIN rms.sa_store_day AS sd 
        ON th.store_day_seq_no = sd.store_day_seq_no
    JOIN rms.sa_tran_item AS ti
        ON ti.tran_seq_no = th.tran_seq_no
WHERE sd.store in (3003) --in (3003) use in if more than 1 value
    AND sd.business_date = '01-JAN-2015'
    AND th.tran_type IN ('SALE','RETURN') 
GROUP BY 
    sd.store;
```

When I add other columns of another table it is showing different values...

Comment: Are you having a reference key to JOIN the two tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is ok.

```
SELECT 
    t1.store,
    SUM(t1.Value) AS Sum_Value
FROM rms.sa_tran_head t1
INNER JOIN sa_store_day t2 ON t1.store_day_seq_no = t2.store_day_seq_no 
WHERE t2.store IN ( 3003 )
  AND t2.business_date = '01-JAN-2015'
  AND t1.tran_type IN ( 'SALE' , 'RETURN' ) 
GROUP BY t1.store
```

Comment: SELECT sd.store, SUM(TH.VALUE) AS GROSS , SUM(ti.qty) AS QTY
FROM rms.sa_tran_head th
JOIN rms.sa_store_day sd 
ON th.store_day_seq_no = sd.store_day_seq_no
JOIN rms.sa_tran_item ti
on ti.tran_seq_no = th.tran_seq_no
WHERE sd.store in (3003) --in (3003) use in if more than 1 value
AND sd.business_date = '01-JAN-2015'
AND th.tran_type IN ('SALE','RETURN') 
group by sd.store;

When i am adding the other column to above query value is changing... can you help me..

Comment: Depends on if the original query's sub-select contains duplicates or not. If it did, this query's SUM is wrong because same item can be included several times. First do a DISTINCT on irms.sa_store_day to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I assumed `store_day_seq_no` is FK for the table `rms.sa_store_day` and the query with `JOIN` like this,

```
SELECT 
    sd.store, 
    SUM(sd.value) AS [Sum]
FROM rms.sa_tran_head AS th
    JOIN rms.sa_store_day AS sd 
        ON th.store_day_seq_no = sd.store_day_seq_no
WHERE 
    sd.store = 3003 --in (3003) use in if more than 1 value
    AND sd.business_date = '01-JAN-2015'
    AND th.tran_type IN ('SALE','RETURN') 
GROUP BY 
    sd.store;
```

Comment: SELECT sd.store, SUM(TH.VALUE) AS GROSS , SUM(ti.qty) AS QTY
FROM rms.sa_tran_head th
JOIN rms.sa_store_day sd 
ON th.store_day_seq_no = sd.store_day_seq_no
JOIN rms.sa_tran_item ti
on ti.tran_seq_no = th.tran_seq_no
WHERE sd.store in (3003) --in (3003) use in if more than 1 value
AND sd.business_date = '01-JAN-2015'
AND th.tran_type IN ('SALE','RETURN') 
group by sd.store;



When I am adding other column of other table the" value" is changing... can you pls help me out

Comment: @SreerangaVinjamuri can you please post the `schema` for all the tables.

Comment: VALUE                                                           NUMBER(20,4)
TRAN_SEQ_NO                    NOT NULL                         NUMBER(20)

Comment: @SreerangaVinjamuri please post all the table's schema, so that we can identify the issue.

Comment: i am unable to post it is showing too long..  in comment